# Unity3D invalid token error on official code from documentation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i was trying to set up simple ad system in my game in unity but the rewarded ads script from unity documentation is giving me invalid token error and i have no idea why

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class RewardedAdsButton : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{
    [SerializeField] Button _showAdButton;
    [SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Rewarded_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOSAdUnitId = "Rewarded_iOS";
    public string _adUnitId = null;
#if UNITY_IOS
        _adUnitId = _iOSAdUnitId;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        _adUnitId = _androidAdUnitId;
#endif
```

> Assets\Scripts\RewardedAdsButton.cs(14,13): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> Assets\Scripts\RewardedAdsButton.cs(14,31): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is extremely misleading in this case!

You can't just reassign a field on class level. Especially not using other non constant fields! You can't have this outside of any method.

---

This is probably supposed to happen in a method like e.g. in `Awake`

```
public class RewardedAdsButton : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{
    [SerializeField] Button _showAdButton;
    [SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Rewarded_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOSAdUnitId = "Rewarded_iOS";

    [NonSerialized] public string _adUnitId = null;

    private void Awake ()
    {
#if UNITY_IOS
        _adUnitId = _iOSAdUnitId;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        _adUnitId = _androidAdUnitId;
#endif
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Or alternatively I would actually rather simply use a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) like e.g.

```
public class RewardedAdsButton : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{
    [SerializeField] Button _showAdButton;
    [SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Rewarded_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOSAdUnitId = "Rewarded_iOS";

    public string _adUnitId
    {
        get
        {
#if UNITY_IOS
            return _iOSAdUnitId;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
            return _androidAdUnitId;
#else
            return null;
#endif
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! that seems to work. Also yes it was official implementation, here is the link https://docs.unity.com/ads/ImplementingRewardedAdsUnity.htm

Comment: @kpcttobee oh boy .. then I am sorry for that part! And someone should tell them .. it makes indeed no sense the way they have it there

Comment: @kpcttobee actually reported it right away with a link here ;) hopefully gets fixed in the future

Comment: They updated the page on 07 January 2022 and it is not fixed yet...

Comment: Also none of the solutions provided by @derHugo works for me. I get this error :  Assets\Scripts\RewardedAdsButton.cs(5,14): error CS0101: The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'RewardedAdsButton'

 plus 10 more like this:  Assets\Scripts\RewardedAdsButton.cs(36,17): error CS0111: Type 'RewardedAdsButton' already defines a member called 'OnUnityAdsAdLoaded' with the same parameter types       Anyone can enlight me to the solution? Many tks !

Comment: @kpcttobee how do you make it works? Tks!

Comment: @H_7 i used DerHugo solution and it worked

Comment: @kpcttobee It is fixed now. I copy paste the code from official document and got no errors now.

Comment: @H_7 after I reported the issue with the doc it was updated with initializing the field in `Awake` ;)

Comment: Great! @derHugo